# Почему неактивна опция "install launcher for all users" при установке питона?

Tags: python, установка

Устанавливала раньше, окошко вылазило похожее только возле install now был значок администрирования желто-синий, теперь нет и галочку нельзя поставить где серый текст. Все ли нормально? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]ло

Comment: Я думаю, вы запускаете установщик от имени пользователя. Попробуйте запустить от имени администратора.

Comment: Я его не запускала, он мне не предлагает скачать от имени администратора, как раньше. Хотя скачиваю тот же самый. А предлагает просто скачать. Открыть его не получается

Comment: Скачиваемый файл тот же самый. Разница лишь в том, от чьего имени его открывать. Посмотрите в интернете, как открыть файл от имени администратора.
Можете пояснить, что значит "открыть его не получается"?

Comment: Не получалось открыть, нажимаю открыть вылазит то же окошко скачивания, скачиваю, запускаю, то же самое окошко, скачала другой питон 3.12 скачался и открывается черное окно, видимо теперь всё в порядке

Comment: 1) Вы пробовали нажимать именно "Запустить от имени администратора"? 2) Почему вы решили, что открытие чёрного окна означает, что всё в порядке? Вообще 3.12 - более новая версия, так что вы правильно сделали.

Comment: Вообще вам важно именно установить питон для всех пользователей?
Если нет, то можете установить его просто для себя. В этом случае просто он установится в вашу папку пользователя. Но пользоваться вы им сможете точно так же.
Только галочку "Add Python 3.** to PATH" советую нажать.

Comment: 1) да, в прошлом питоне 3.9.7 все время при попытке открыть вылазило окно скачивания, хотя после скачивания пишет что уже скачен. Тоесть я просто скачиваю его по кругу и никакого результата. А 3.12 открылся сразу после скачивания

Comment: галочку на PATH нажала да